# Is GTA Online cross-platform?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Grand Theft Auto Online exists on five different platforms: XBox 360, PS3, XBox One, PS4, and PC. Do any of these play on the same servers, allowing people on differing platforms to play together?

Comment: Posting a single canonical question to amalgamate the various GTA Online cross-platform questions per [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11074/30115).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No**. No combinations of those five platforms use the same servers in a way that would allow players on different systems to play in the same lobby.

Part of the issues involved with doing so include the fact that current generation platforms (Xbox One, PS4, PC) allow 30 concurrent players at a time per lobby, while the previous generation allows only 16.

Another issue is that, reportedly, there are policies among the console manufacturers that are highly against cross-platform multiplayer. At least between each other.

So as it stands, each of the five versions of GTA Online are separate from the other four. The closest you can get to cross-platform is by buying the game on a current-gen system, and transferring online character progress from previous generation version. There is also the a slight caveat that the XBox One is adding backwards compatibility for 360 games. It should be noted that in this case you would be able to play the ***Xbox 360 version of the game*** on either console with other people playing the ***Xbox 360 version of the game*** on either console.

Comment: In that case, what does the controller icon next to a player's name resemble?

Comment: @shadow AFAIK (from playing on pc) the controller icon is used to indicate whether they are playing with mouse&keyboard or controller.

Comment: I just confirmed this. How sad :(

Answer (score 3):

The **only** exception to a universal **No** answer would be in regards to Xbox One's backward compatibility feature.

This feature (available since November 2015) allows you to play Xbox 360 games on the Xbox One.  This includes multiplayer features so that you can play against other players using an Xbox 360.  More details can be found from the official site here:

[Xbox One Backward Compatibility](http://www.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-one/backward-compatibility)

To avoid confusion, when you play an Xbox 360 game on the Xbox One console you can play against anyone that is either using an Xbox 360 console **or** the Xbox One backward compatibility feature.

Here is a relevant question from the [feature's FAQ](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360-faq#af9a8c98cbd64a32a45b4ca16e56060a):

> **Can I do multiplayer gaming with friends who are playing the game on Xbox 360 or Xbox One?**
>
> Yes. For games that offer multiplayer gaming, you'll be able to play with others who own the title on Xbox 360.

GTA V was **not** on the **initial** 100+ supported games list.  The list of supported games can be found on the official site here:

[Supported Games](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility/available-games)

Note that more games are due to be added over time through future updates.  The warning at the top of the current list is as follows:

> Initial titles with more to come. Games are subject to change.

Comment: Thats a big if. I would disagree that it would ever happen, as even when you play on one, you're accessing different servers. I don't think we should cover potential future scenarios, on the basis that realistically, lots could happen in the future.

Comment: You access the same servers.  It works on Halo, Gears of War etc so far.  It is rolling out across more games in the next update.  My answer is to cover the exception to the case whereby someone asks "Can I play Xbox One vs. Xbox 360" - which may be "yes" very shortly.

Comment: Thats a big "may". While this answer is good, it isn't exact, it is just a possibility.

Comment: According to the site, regular in-console updates and promotional videos this is a big feature for them (as you can see, the initial roll out was over 100 games, with more to follow).  This isn't a speculative answer as it is a fact that they will be rolling out more games with future updates.  I don't think this is a "big if" or "big may", more a "when".

Comment: I agree that it is probably going to be released as a supported game, however I'm not sure if this likely-to-happen-speculation should be posted as an answer.

Comment: It answers the question as "No" but a possible exception.  I explained the exception, and how it works.  I gave links to the currently supported list and official portal to the feature.  The answer can only be incorrect if Xbox official announce this one game will not be supported.  I believe they have already committed to all games for gold titles (or so it appears, looking at the list).

Comment: Actually, the answer is "No" but there can be only 1 exception.  It doesn't speculate on other exceptions, only that there can be only one (not an intentional Highlander reference, btw).  This is a correct answer.  Nothing I said is false, irrelevant, unresearched (I even tried playing Rainbow Six and Sonic through the One).

Comment: Ok then, please keep a close eye on announcements by Xbox/Microsoft and keep this answer updated.

Comment: Of course, I also future proofed it by adding a direct link to the supported list just in case I miss it by a few days.

Comment: This isn't much of an *exception*. By the sound of it you are still only playing an **XBox 360 game** with other people playing the **XBox 360 game**. You might be playing *on* the One, but you are still playing the 360 *version*. Although I suppose it is noteworthy enough to mention.

Comment: @TrentHawkins - yes, everyone playing the 360 game, but playing on the One.  It's a new feature that is surely going to bring traffic to this site.