# GTA V online multiplayer: I know two consoles are needed but can they be different? xbox360 and xbox one

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, grand-theft-auto-online

I want to play in the same house against friends in GTA online. I have an Xbox one and xbox 360 but only have game for xbox 360. If I get the game for xbox one can we play together using same wifi and in same channel with people and complete races, deathmatches, missions, etc. together?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr No.

Unfortunately, Grand Theft Auto online does not support cross platform play. So unless you have two Xbox 360's or two Xbox One's, you will not be able to play with your friend at the same time.

This question was asked at some point in the past, and it really points out that one of the bigger issues is size of player lobbies. The newer platforms, PS4, PC, Xbox One, support player lobbies of up to 30 players whereas your Xbox 360 will only support 16. Here's the question the last time it was asked with a more in depth response.

[Is GTA Online cross-platform?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245063/is-gta-online-cross-platform)