# Is GTA 5 backwards compatible between Xbox 360 and Xbox One S?

Tags: xbox-one, grand-theft-auto-online, backwards-compatibility

If my friend uses the backwards compatibility to play GTA 5 360 version on Xbox One S, and I use the Xbox One S version of the game, can I still play GTA 5 with him?

We will both be playing on our Xbox One S's, just different versions of the game - the Xbox 360 version and the Xbox One S version.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. There is no cross console compatibility. Since one of you will be playing an Xbox 360 version, and the other playing an Xbox one version, it'd be considered two different "consoles" even if one of them is a Xbox 360 emulator

Also, this has been asked before (kinda) - [Is GTA Online cross-platform?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/245063/191922)

[GTA V online multiplayer: I know two consoles are needed but can they be different? xbox360 and xbox one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/322530/191922)